# Optical flow in image processing

Tags: image-processing

I dont quit understand optical flow in image. For the follwing question, I think the fastest runner would be the third runner as its optical flow in x direction is -13.3 which is bigger than the rest, so he is ahead the others. Is it right?
And what does it mean by margin?

[image]

Comment: "By what margin?" means "How much faster is the fastest runner compared to the second fastest runner?"

Answer (score 0):

If we assume, that the pixel shrinking is linear, then the second runner would be the fastest, as 2 times -20.1 is the biggest of the three